# Racket 'All' parameterization

Tags: polymorphism, racket, typed-racket

I got confused while reading the official Racket docs regarding the 'All' keyword [found here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/type-ref.html?q=all#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt%29._.All%29%29)

Consider the example code:

```
(: list-length : (All (A) (Listof A) -> Natural))
(define (list-length lst)
  (if (null? lst)
    0
    (add1 (list-length (cdr lst)))))


(test (list-length (list 1 2 3)) => 3)
(test (list-length (list 1 2 "3")) => 3)
```

I'd expect 'All' to allow polymorphism for the list while forcing the list elements to be of the same type.

But the second test passes, so my assumption is apparently wrong.

What did I get wrong and what is the difference between 'All' and 'any'?

(i.e `(All (A) (Listof A) ... )` vs `(Listof any)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of `All` is correct. What happens here is that Typed Racket is picking a type that includes all the list elements. Unlike in Java or ML, in Typed Racket there are types that include both numbers and strings, such as `(U Number String)`, which is what Typed Racket picks here.

The `Any` type includes everything, so it's much less precise than `(U Number String)`.

Comment: So what's the point using `(All (A) (Listof A) ... )` if it's same as `(Listof any)`?

Comment: It's not that same as `(Listof Any)`. If you use `car` on a `(Listof Any)` the result will have type `Any`.